# JSON.NET Error reading JObject

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am sending a JSON object via AJAX and Web Api to my Server:

```
var data = [
  ["fdsfsd", "Kifdsfa", "fsdfsa", "fadsf", "fasdfsd", "fadsf", "fasdfsd"],
  ["2008", "-5", "11", "12", "13"],
  ["2009", "20", "-11", "14", "13"],
  ["2010", "30", "15", "-12", "readOnly"]
];

$.ajax({
        url: '../webapi/Products',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "text", 
        data: "="+JSON.stringify( data ),
        success: function (test) {
                alert(test);
            },
            error: function (test) {
                alert("Error");
            }
```

so i am getting on server the value which i want to parse with JSON.NET:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value )
{
      JObject o = JObject.Parse(@value);
}
```

This throws the exception:

```
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object:
StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Why? The value seems to be right to me?

Comment: Did you print value on the server to check if the syntax is correct? My Guess is, you are getting a json array and not a json object

Comment: yes it seems to be array. So there is no way to convert this to a JObject right? How can i convert this array e.g. to a DataTable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

json.stringify will create the following json string:

```
[
  ["fdsfsd", "Kifdsfa", "fsdfsa", "fadsf", "fasdfsd", "fadsf", "fasdfsd"],
  ["2008", "-5", "11", "12", "13"],
  ["2009", "20", "-11", "14", "13"],
  ["2010", "30", "15", "-12", "readOnly"]
]
```

Which is a jsonArray and not a JsonObject. So on server side you'll have to read it using `JArray a = JArray.Parse(@value);`

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing over this, I'd suggest changing

```
data: "="+JSON.stringify( data ),
```

to

```
data: "myJSON="+JSON.stringify( data ),
```

...since jQuery expects either an object to serialize, or a valid query string, and then listening for that posted variable. I don't think you can just POST a bunch of data without assigning it as the value of a name/value pair.