# Json ,net is not working

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to parse an with json net in c#. And i am using json .net

But it is showing the following exception

```
Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

i am creating json string with jquery. And the example of string is as follows.

```
 {"0":{"tyreId":"","tyreNum":"dsf","tyreSecondHand":"false","tyreReplace":"true"},"1":{"tyreId":"","tyreNum":"gfd","tyreSecondHand":"true","tyreReplace":"true"}}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error reading JObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823109/json-net-error-reading-jobject)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JSON document represents an object (`JObject`) with the keys `"0"` and `"1"`.  It is not a true array, but rather an object that somewhat mimics an array.

Either read the document as an object, or fix the document to be a real array:

```
[{"tyreId":"","tyreNum":"dsf","tyreSecondHand":"false","tyreReplace":"true"},{"tyreId":"","tyreNum":"gfd","tyreSecondHand":"true","tyreReplace":"true"}]
```