# Can't parse JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to read a local .json file using `StreamReader`:

My code:

```
using (var jsonReader = new StreamReader(pathToMyJsonFile)) 
{
     string json = jsonReader.ReadToEnd();
     dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
     foreach (var item in array)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(item.fuzzy);
     }

}
```

My json:

```
[
    {
        "fuzzy": "12345",
        "name": "{jon-errand}",
        "email": "person@gmail.com",
        "lights": "red",
        "friends": "Elizabeth",
        "traits": {
            "Hair": "brown",
            "Eyes": "yellow"
        }
    }
]
```

I get the exception: `Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject.` I have tried looking at the SO answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364023/error-reading-jarray-from-jsonreader-current-jsonreader-item-is-not-an-array) but I am sure my json is a real array. Without changing the above json, how can I read this json file in a useful way so I can pull out specific fields? Such as getting the `email` field as `person@gmail.com`?

Comment: I don't see "senders" anywhere in your JSON.

Comment: I can't see any `senders` in json

Comment: Sorry. Post has been edited.

Comment: What Json.Net version are you using?

Comment: When I try this, I don't get any errors, it works fine.

Comment: Do you need to DeserializeObject<dynamic>() maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: This code works fine for me for everything except the very first version of Json.NET on NuGet (3.5.8) - and that throws a different exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var obj  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(File.ReadAllText(pathToMyJsonFile));
```

And your classes

```
public class Traits
{
    public string Hair { get; set; }
    public string Eyes { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string fuzzy { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string lights { get; set; }
    public string friends { get; set; }
    public Traits traits { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(pathToMyJsonFile));

foreach (var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.name + " " + item.traits.Hair);
}
```

Comment: Json.Net should handle dynamic's fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Comment: Is there any way to do this without making additional classes?

Comment: @Liam Of course, But getting help from compiler can be better in most cases.

Comment: How does your edit differ from the code in the question?

Comment: what's the difference between your answer and the OPs? They seem practically identical?

Comment: Thanks for the help! You may want to clarify in your answer that the code above and below the `EDIT` are mutually exclusive and work independent of each other.

Answer (score -1):

You can deserialize in JArray

```
JArray array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);
foreach (var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["fuzzy"]); // Prints 12345
}
```